# nested for loop with where condition in Xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I need to filter  tag value from the following sample XML.

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <id root="3930E379-5C54-477D-8DB2-F6C92BC08C691" />
    <component>
        <structuredBody>
            <component>
                <section>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4"/>
                    <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" 
          codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS"/>
                    <title>HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS</title>
                    <text>Patient slipped and fell on ice, twisting her ankle as she fell.
    </text>
                </section>
            </component>
            <component>
                <section>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.5"/>
                    <code code="10164-3" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.12" 
          codeSystemName="LOINC1" displayName="DEMO"/>
                    <title>DEMO HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS</title>
                    <text>DEMO Patient slipped and fell on ice, twisting her ankle as she fell.
    </text>
                </section>
            </component>
        </structuredBody>
    </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

there are many file like this in my collection(i am using eXits-db), and i need to filter based on 'root' attribute in `<id>` tag and 'root' attribute in `<templateId>` tag. and the result i need is only the `<title>` text value.

Following is the query i tried.But is shows all the title values(not the one which match my condition).

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
(
    for $prod in collection("/db/netspectivedb/")/d:ClinicalDocument
    where $prod/d:id/@root/string()='3930E379-5C54-477D-8DB2-F6C92BC08C691' 
        and $prod/d:component/d:structuredBody/d:component/d:section/d:templateId/@root/string()='1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4'
    return  $prod/d:component/d:structuredBody/d:component/d:section/d:title/text()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that `$prod` in your XQuery references `ClinicalDocument`, which isn't specific enough for your purpose. You want to loop through `component` or `section` inside `structuredBody` instead to start with, for example :

```
declare namespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
(
    for $section in collection("/db/netspectivedb/")/d:ClinicalDocument[d:id/@root eq '3930E379-5C54-477D-8DB2-F6C92BC08C691']/d:component/d:structuredBody/d:component/d:section
    where $section/d:templateId/@root eq '1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4'
    return  $section/d:title/text()
)
```

or using nested `for` as you specifically asked. Nested `for` also turns out to be more readable in this case  :

```
declare namespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
(
    for $prod in collection("/db/netspectivedb/")/d:ClinicalDocument
    for $section in $prod/d:component/d:structuredBody/d:component/d:section
    where $prod/d:id/@root eq '3930E379-5C54-477D-8DB2-F6C92BC08C691' 
        and $section/d:templateId/@root eq '1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4'
    return  $section/d:title/text()
)
```

I am using `eq` instead of `=` above since we mean to do *value comparison* (read more: https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/comparison-operators-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same thing with a single XPath expression:

```
declare namespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
collection("/db/netspectivedb/")/
  d:ClinicalDocument[d:id/@root eq '3930E379-5C54-477D-8DB2-F6C92BC08C691']/
  d:component/d:structuredBody/d:component/
  d:section[d:templateId/@root eq '1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4']/d:title/text()
```